# Is there a perfect game where there can be no draw and no chance is involved

Tags: game-theory

Is there a game which is perfect, that is:

- always provides a decisive victor, and
- involves no component of luck

Possible games which would be perfect or near-perfect might involve the pie rule. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pie_rule

For the purposes of this question, a 'decisive victor' means that there is no tie, draw or stalemate- the game always ends with one player winning and another losing.

'Luck' includes any arbitrary decision outside the strategy of the players, such as deciding who gets to go first by flipping a coin.

In other words, what I'm asking is: is there a strategy game in which neither player has an advantage due to luck, but one of them must win.

It seems to me that there cannot be, because otherwise if two 'perfect' players played against each other, what could be the result?

Comment: The game in which player 1 always wins and player 2 always loses.

Comment: A game of armageddon chess. The rules are the same as normal chess but if there is a draw black wins.

Comment: Checkers? Tic-Tac-Toe? Nim? I could go on.

Comment: @Meelo In tic-tac-toe, both players can force a draw, so a _decisive_ winner may not exist.

Comment: What do you mean by "perfect"?

Comment: You should expand your question. As @EmilKerimov said, just making P1 win always solves your question.

Comment: I presume you're looking for a _symmetric_ game with those properties, which would rule out the options mentioned above. Then I would propose [matching pennies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_pennies). Of course, in the Nash equilibrium of matching pennies, each player wins with probability 1/2. Given each player's action choice, there is a deterministic winner or loser (no chance, no ties). However, in equilibrium, players endogenously (and optimally) use chance to determine their actions.

Comment: If player 1 always wins and player 2 always loses, then the luck of deciding who goes first has a (decisive) influence on the game. In Armageddon chess, I imagine black would have a significant advantage. What I mean by a perfect game is, as Shane commented, a symmetric game, but also one in which the optimal strategy doesn't involve a random choice between alternative actions.

Comment: I must second RowanS. Armageddon chess is believed by the masters to be balanced, and meets the other criteria.